# Curves in plot do not start on the vertical axis

Tags: plotting

I am a Mathematica novice and have plotted two curves in a frame. I am wondering why both curves do not start directly on the vertical axis. There seems to be a small gap between where the curves start and the vertical axis. Is there a way to remove this gap? My code and the output figure are below.

```
Show[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[Cos[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: `PlotRangePadding -> 0`

Comment: Btw, this aleady happens with `Plot[Sin[t],{t,0,5},Frame->True]`. Please make sure to read [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reproducing the problem

I can reproduce the issue with this shorter and easier-to-read code.

```
Plot[
    {
        Sin[t],
        Cos[t]
    }
    , {t, 0, 5}
    , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
]
```

[image]

## Solution

This does not happen if [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) is made explicit.

```
Plot[
    {
        Sin[t],
        Cos[t]
    }
    , {t, 0, 5}
    , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
    , PlotRange -> {{0,5},All}
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
]
```

[image]

This does not happen if [`PlotRangePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) is set to zero (credit to @cvgmt in the comments).

```
Plot[
    {
        Sin[t],
        Cos[t]
    }
    , {t, 0, 5}
    , PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , PlotRangePadding -> 0
]
```

[image]